# Hiding non-delivery report email address in outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, smtp, email-client

I am sending an email from a specific address (i.e  user@mydomain.com) with a unique sender address to do [bounce-tracking(link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_delivery_report)[(link2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511487/modifying-the-from-smtp-header-without-affecting-the-mime-from-header).
The issue is that when the message is received in outlook it is diplayed as if sent by the bounce-tracking address (which is from a different domain, might be relevant?), displayed as from: **"tracking_address@tracking_domain.com on behalf of real_address@domain.com"**

Is there a way to hide this irrelevant and confusing information from the user? gmail does not display it.

Comment: You might be able to hide it through the use of a custom Outlook plug-in.  the reason Gmail does not display it is because they have additional capabilities because all emails are displayed throught the use of html.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't see how the use of HTML is relevant, but I would like the recipients of the email to not see it. It's not meant for me but for my recipients.

Comment: You won't be able to hide this information on a client's computer because the information is accurate. You are actually sending the address on behalf of your other address. **Google doesn't ALWAYS hide it.** Google only hides it when it can be determined that the two addresses are one in the same.

Comment: @Ramhound If I keep both addresses are on the same domain, will it be hidden on outlook too?